# Python Packaging with Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tree like this

```
src
  __init__.py  
  my_app
    __init__.py
    db.py
    config.py
tests
  __init__.py
  test_db.py
```

In `db.py` I've got an import like this

```
from config import my_func
```

This works fine when I run db.py by itself (python /src/my_app/db.py).

When I try to run it with pytest, then it says, there is no module named config in the db.py file.  If I prepend the path

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
from config import my_func
```

Then I get an error from pytest that says

```
from src.my_app.db import foo
"No module found named src"
```

I just don't understand what's wrong. I've looked at dozens of posts and feel like I have this right, but apparently not.

Comment: Should you not be adding `src` to the path so you can just import `my_app`? Also maybe try printing out the sys path to make sure its the folder you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to avoid using any `sys.path.insert`/`sys.path.append` hacks.

Instead, make sure your `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly, it should include the path your `src` directory is located in. Otherwise, the `src.my_app.db` import won't be resolved.

Say, you have the following path to your `src` directory: `/Users/michael/py_project/src`
And your `tests` dir is located on the following path: `/Users/michael/py_project/tests`
Then your `PYTHONPATH` should include the `/Users/michael/py_project` path.

You can set it by running:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/michael/py_project
```

Double-check the `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly before running tests:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Once the `PYTHONPATH` is set, you should be able to run `pytest tests` from the `/Users/michael/py_project` directory.

**UPD:**
Also, make sure you're using absolute imports rather than relative ones. So in your case, in `db.py` you should import `my_func` with `from src.my_app.config import my_func` instead.

Comment: While this resolves the pytest aspect, the issue remains about running the db.py file directly and the conflict that’s introduced

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: use absolute imports rather than relative ones.  

So in your case, in `db.py` you should import `my_func` with `from src.my_app.config import my_func`.  
And in `tests` the import should be absolute as well: `from src.my_app.db import ...`