# moduleNotFoundError: No module names error occurs

Tags: python, function, init

If i want to use the function hello(), what should i do.

I am using VS Code

So My directory looks like this

---

project

- myapp

  - __init__.py  (have hello( ) function)
  - test.py
- run.py

---

in __init__.py file

```py
def hello():
   print('hello')
```

in run.py file, if i wrote

```py
from myapp import hello
hello()
```

it works

However if i try the same thing in test.py, it won't work.

when i searched for answer, someone told me to put sys.path.append(),

i have tried to put un test.py file

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('path\project\myapp')
from myapp import hello
hello()
```

but still have same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Packaging with Pytest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76177509/python-packaging-with-pytest)

Comment: Never touch `sys.path` unless you're absolutely sure what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

Welp in run.py file

instead of

from myapp import hello

```py
from __init__ import hello
hello()
```

this works well

Answer (score -1):

you can use `from __init__ import hello` or other options given here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40327801)